# Selenium IDE API get test script code

Tags: firefox-addon, selenium-ide

In my custom Firefox plugin for Selenium IDE I need to get a test script text from Selenium IDE window, but it seems that no plugin API is provided for this. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say test script text can you clarify what you mean? Is it the log you need? some text recorded in the running of the script? Do you need the actual code of the full test script? etc.

Comment: I need recorded xml sourse code of test

Comment: You should just be able to open the test script in a text editor for this. Either that or in the selenium IDE window, click the source tab.

Comment: The problem is that I need to do it programmatically

Comment: It is not clear what you want to reach, but looks like IDE is not option for you. Try java + webdrver

Answer (score 0):

you can launch the selenium ide from CLI and browser whatever a user will perform in the browser the IDE will record,
Now the thing to figure out is you need to stop the recording and save the script from IDE through CLI so that it will be available for later use else it overwrites the file. I too stuck in it.

Launching the Selenium IDE CLI command:

```
firefox -chrome chrome://selenium-ide/content
```

Launch the firefox browser by:

```
firefox firefox.exe
```

it's inappropriate but now if you perform action any one firefox browser then it will record them. by default on launch the record button is on.